# What is the difference between 'contrib' and 'non-free' packages repositories?

Tags: debian, repository, debian-policy

Although I like Debian for various reasons, it is not always easy to find some documentation on specific aspects of this distribution and its policies.

My question is: what is the difference between `contrib` and `non-free` packages repositories?

From the little explanations I could find, if I am not mistaken:

- `non-free` is for packages whose licences are not free
- `contrib` for dependencies of `non-free` packages (which make them not part of Debian)

But it seems odd to me to have two repositories for, so to speak, the same purpose, which is making available non free software inside Debian.

I would like to know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[*non-free*](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#component) packages are packages not complying to the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines) definition. E.g.:

[`nvidia-driver`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/nvidia-driver) which provides a proprietary driver.

[*contrib*](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#component) packages are packages that do comply with the DFSG, but depend on *non-free* packages, or which depend on some non-free software downloaded (by the package or having to be downloaded manually) to work properly. So they don't end up in `main`. E.g.:

[`bumblebee-nvidia`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/bumblebee-nvidia) which while DFSG compliant, isn't really useful without the *non-free* package `nvidia-driver`, so it's put in the `contrib` section, or

[`vice`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/vice) which requires to download (while respecting copyrights and laws) ROMs to work properly.

If somebody doesn't want to or can't use *non-free* software, that person most probably doesn't need or won't be able to use software depending on it, so it's more useful to put them separately in a *contrib* section. That person won't even have to download the *contrib* section.

UPDATE: the software in *contrib*, *and its sources* are still available for free use. Interesting parts could be reused in an other project, or the *non-free* (or non available) parts it depends upon could be replaced (e.g.: replace graphics, music etc. assets for a game engine in *contrib*). Having it separate from *non-free* helps to know which parts can be reused.

trivia: the [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd) was initially created by removing any mention of Debian in DFSG.

Comment: I don't really understand the benefit to either Debian or its users of seperating `non-free` and `contrib`. What is the actual advantage gained? As an end-user who doesn't care if a program contains non-free code, both `non-free` and `contrib` are fine by me. As an end-user who *does* care, both are off-limits for me. What is the actual advantage?

Comment: Like MechMK1, I am puzzled by this, and, even if I should have maybe have it written clearer in my question, that is also an aspect I would like to an answer to.

Comment: You can reuse and modify code from contrib to adapt it to an other project, because the source is available as any source from "main". You probably can't do this when it's from non-free, either the source licence doesn't let you do enough, or there is no source at all. If the end user is a "normal" end user who doesn't attempt to do anything beside what is distributed, I can imagine contrib and non-free would look the same

Comment: Also sometimes you can replace the non-free parts by free parts. The kind of thing that could be done in theory with some game engines in contrib and their assets (graphics, music...) in non-free or nowhere. The split made it clear it was possible to do this.

Comment: so how come the package `torbrowser-launcher` is part of contrib? All of its dependencies are entirely in Main. It was moved to contrib because torbrowser executes code outside of its source, and that violates DFSG.
But if it violates DFSG, how can it be in contrib (which is only for DFSG-compliant packages). The condtition it broke:
"must not require or recommend a package outside of _main_ for
  compilation or execution"
but by fact, it doesn't require a 'package', and if we say 'any code' instead of package, then it cant be in contrib and should be in non-free

Comment: Additionally, `firefox-esr` (and `firefox` in sid) both still have DRM available, which breaks the same rule, yet both of those are still in main.
I mean don't get me wrong, i dont want debian to ship with a crippled version of firefox, or start going insane and moving to `non-free` any package that has any ability to run functional code outside of its own source,
but it's still inconsistent

Comment: I can think of other examples too, even something like `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` requires `firmware-amd-graphics` which is strictly non-free in every sense of the definition, and literally will not run (not to be confused with the `radeon` kernel driver, not a single GPU that uses the newer `amdgpu` kernel driver can run without the firmware, so any Radeon RX 400+ series card only uses `amdgpu` kernel driver )
yet `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` is neatly in main

Answer (score 9):

Defined on the Debian Policy Manual:

[2.2.2. The contrib archive area](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#the-contrib-archive-area)

> The contrib archive area contains supplemental packages intended to work with the Debian distribution, but which require software outside of the distribution to either build or function.
>
> Every package in contrib must comply with the DFSG.
>
> In addition, the packages in contrib
>
> - must not be so buggy that we refuse to support them, and
> - must meet all policy requirements presented in this manual.
>
> Examples of packages which would be included in contrib are:
>
> free packages which require contrib, non-free packages or packages which are not in our archive at all for compilation or execution, and
>
> wrapper packages or other sorts of free accessories for non-free programs.

[2.2.3. The non-free archive area](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#the-non-free-archive-area)

> The non-free archive area contains supplemental packages intended to work with the Debian distribution that do not comply with the DFSG or have other problems that make their distribution problematic. They may not comply with all of the policy requirements in this manual due to restrictions on modifications or other limitations.
>
> Packages must be placed in non-free if they are not compliant with the DFSG or are encumbered by patents or other legal issues that make their distribution problematic.
>
> In addition, the packages in non-free
>
> - must not be so buggy that we refuse to support them, and
> - must meet all policy requirements presented in this manual that it is
>     possible for them to meet.

Further reading:

- [Philosophy of the GNU Project](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.en.html)
- [Categories of free and nonfree software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/categories.en.html)
- [When Free Software Depends on Nonfree](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/when-free-depends-on-nonfree.en.html)
- [Explaining Why We Don't Endorse Other Systems](https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.en.html)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#s-contrib

> The contrib archive area contains supplemental packages intended to work with the Debian distribution, but which require software outside of the distribution to either build or function.

This software could very well be software that is not available in `main` despite being free. You just can't get it from debian.

Comment: It's not that you "cannot get it from Debian", it's just not part of the Debian distribution per se.